# parcel js validator-eslint dependency conflict

Tags: validation, eslint, parcel

Cannot install @parcel/validator-eslint with dependency error

- parcel: 2.7.0
- eslint: 8.23.1

```
  {
    "error": {
      "code": "ERESOLVE",
      "summary": "unable to resolve dependency tree",
      "detail": "\nWhile resolving: b2c-spa-web@1.0.0\nFound: eslint@8.23.1\nnode_modules/eslint\n  dev eslint@\"^8.23.1\" from the root project\n\nCould not resolve dependency:\npeer eslint@\"^6.0.0\" from         
  @parcel/validator-eslint@2.7.0\nnode_modules/@parcel/validator-eslint\n  dev @parcel/validator-eslint@\"*\" from the root project\n\nFix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry\nthis command with --force, or   
  --legacy-peer-deps\nto accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.\n\nSee C:\\Users\\BRITDW7\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\eresolve-report.txt for a full report."
    }
  }
```

.parcelrc

```
{
    "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
    "validators": {
        "*.{js,mjs,jsm,jsx,es6,cjs,ts,tsx}": [
            "@parcel/validator-eslint"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the surface, it means the eslint 8 plug-in was not compatible to parcel 2. There is an issue created

[@parcel/validator-eslint won't work with ESLint v8+](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/8063)